# API Inconsistencies

Tags: discussion, api-v2

In my opinion, one of the hallmarks of a good API is that it is self-consistent.  It establishes easy-to-remember conventions and then follows them.

As I'm trying to adopt the 2.0 API, I'm finding a whole bunch of inconsistencies in the API that are making it *really* frustrating to work with.  Here are some of the things that are really bothering me:

- The value for the `sort` query parameter should *always* correspond to a field in the object of the returned JSON.  It usually doesn't.  For example, if I want to sort badges by their `badge_type`, I have to pass in `sort=type`.  It *should* be `sort=badge_type`.  (another example, for tags I do `sort=popular` even though it really should be `sort=count`)
- I should not be able to sort by something that does not correspond to a field in the object returned.  For example, I can sort Tags by "activity" (`sort=activity`), but there's nothing in the returned Tag objects that indicates what that activity is.  If we really want to be able to sort Tags by the time they were last used, then Tags should have a `last_used_date` field that contains the timestamp of the last time the tag was added to a Question, and then I should do `sort=last_used_date`)
- I find it really annoying that some object fields don't make sense in all contexts.  For example, the Badge `user` field is only relevant if I'm requesting awarded badges (i.e. via `/badges/recipients` or `/badges/{ids}/recipients`).  If the field is not always relevant, it *should not* be there.  Instead, the `*/recipients` endpoints should return "Awarded Badge" objects that have `award_count`, `user`, and `badge` fields.
- Tags, Badges, and Users all have `name` (or `display_name`) fields.  So why can't I do `inname=foo` when requesting Badges?  If you're going to offer searching by name on some things, you should offer searching by name on *all* things.

There are more, but these are ones that I remember right now.  As I come across more I'll also post those.

Comment: +1 for the anti popular/activity, they are too ambiguous. Although `award_count` should be on all badges, as when not associated with a user it means the number of times the badge has been awarded site-wide. (separate fields, e.g. total_award_count and user_award_count, might be better)

Comment: @Jonathan. good point on `award_count`, but I definitely think `total_award_count` would be a better name. Making the semantic meaning of a field dependent on the context is a bad idea. Badges, IMO, shouldn't contain *any* user-specific information, because there's nothing inherent about a badge that has to do with a User.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I agree with a bit of this... but not all of it.

`sorts` descend conceptually from the sorts exposed on the sites, you'll note this most strongly from the [question sorts](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) (hot, week, month, activity, and votes).  `popular` on [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular), is another example of something that came more or less directly from the site.  It would be wrong to not expose sorts like `hot` in the API, but there really isn't a meaningful field to be returned there (internally it's a completely opaque decimal number).

Related, I disagree with the idea of sorts mapping to fields explicitly.  This creates the false expectation (that would be essentially impossible to meet, for performance reasons) that you can sort on *all* returned fields.  For overlapping conceptual sorts (which often have overlapping field names), like "when was this object created", we do share sort names (in the example case, `creation`).  I will, however, look into adding `tag.last_activity_date`.

The only example of a field I can think of off hand that's never set is `badge.user` when fetched from `/badges`, `/badges/{ids}`, `/badges/name`, or `/badges/tags` (the other `/badges/*` and `*/badges` methods can and generally do set the `user` field).  I can see where you're coming from, it is a little odd.  However, I think the cure is worse than the disease.  We'd have a type that differs from another by a single field (which means some annoying boiler plate in statically typed consumers) and we'd have split the concept of a badge in two (which would mean more configuration when building a filter that's concerned with the overarching concept of a badge).  It's hardly like this is the only case where a field is *almost always* not set, consider `timed_penalty_date` on `/me` for example*.  All things considered, I believe the cure for this blemish is worse than the disease.

As something of an aside, we don't expose lots of text searching** because it's expensive.  This is why, for example, `/search` exists rather than having `intitle` and `nottagged` on `/questions` (and also why it returns much more heavily cached data, and less of it at that).  the descent of `inname` parameters is also from the sites, you'll notice that we have search boxes on [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users) and [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), but not [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges).  All that being said, I'll looking into what adding that parameter would do to performance; I suspect it can be added and may be of some use (at least, in the tag-based badge case).

<sub>*It being rather hard to authenticate when your account is suspended, rarity of suspension not withstanding.</sub>

<sub>**Note that some tag searching tasks devolve to text search or equivalent performance wise.</sub>

---

[tag.last_activity_date](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag) and `inname` on various [badges methods](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges) have been added as a consquence of this discussion.

Comment: (Comments in order) I'm willing to let things like `hot`, `week`, and `month` slide as sort values on questions, because there's no way for clients to duplicate the algorithm used to determine the "hotness" of a question. But I maintain that *consuming the API is not the same thing as using the site*. The API is for us developers, and thus it should be consistent.  If I'm sorting by the score of a question, then don't call it `votes`, call it `score`.  If I'm sorting by when an object was creation, don't call it `creation`, call it `creation_date`. The sort key should match the object field.

Comment: Badge and User have a many-to-many relationship.  Proper decomposition mandates that the way to model that correctly with a -to-one relationship on one side (which is what JSON can handle) *is* with another object, the Awarded Badge.

I understand that text searching is expensive. It's just frustrating to think "ok, this had `inname`, that had `inname`, this should to. Wait, it doesn't? wtf?".